# TypeScript: Type of another type with one property renamed

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to create a function that transform an object by renaming one property, and properly returns the type of this?

Example:

My input type:

```
type In = {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
};

const in: In = {foo: 'hello', bar: 42};
```

I want to call a function that renames `foo` to `convertedFoo`, while maintaining its type (string), and has a return type that reflects this object.

```
const out = convert(in, 'foo', 'convertedFoo')
```

Now I want `out` to be `{convertedFoo: 'hello', bar: 42}`

I tried

```
function convert<T>(obj: T, oldProp: keyof T, newProp: string): Omit<T, oldProp> & {[newProp]: T[oldProp]} {
    const {[oldProp]: id, ...rest} = obj;

    return {...rest, [newProp]: id};
}
```

But this (obviously) doesn't work since `oldProp` cannot be passed to `Omit` dynamically, and `newProp` cannot be used as a computer property name in a literal.

Is this at all possible to accomplish?

Comment: My guess is no, you're trying to mix types and variables in a weird way. What you're trying to do is essentially defining a type dynamically based on the value of some variables (even if in your example you use static strings).
I don't think it's possible because you're mixing concepts of different worlds (compile time and run time). The core of the function couldn't also be simplified to simply `obj[newProp] = obj[oldProp]; delete obj[oldProp];`? I may have missed the point though, so please clarify if I'm misleading.

Comment: @Stnaire your code mutates `obj`, mine doesn't - it returns a new object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const in_var = {
    foo: 'hello',
    bar: 42,
    step: true
}; // in is keyword
function convert<T, OldProp extends keyof T, NewProp extends string>(obj: T, oldProp: OldProp, newProp: NewProp) {
    const {
        [oldProp]: id,
        ...rest
    } = obj;

    return {
        ...rest,
        [newProp]: id
    } as Omit<T, OldProp> & Record<NewProp, T[OldProp]>;
}
var a = convert(in_var, "foo", "foo_new").foo_new; // intellisense works! (I trust you use Visual Studio Code)
```

Firstly, in is invalid variable name, it's keyword. Then you cannot use `{[newProp]: T[oldProp]}` because you mix values and types. Better was `{[x: NewProp]: T[OldProp]}` but TypeScript throws an error, because it doesn't know if NewProp is string or number. Use Record. I spend one hour for answer, I trust it's correct.